# Array mutation C

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, strtok

I want to tokenize a string by word (using " " as separator), and store a word in another array if it's unique.
However, I get behaviour where these words become undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

````
    int wordCount = 0;
    char wordArray[wordCount+1][256];
    int wordCountArray[wordCount+1];

    char storedInputTemp[strlen(storedInput)];
    strcpy(storedInputTemp, storedInput);

    const char s[2] = " ";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(storedInputTemp, s);

    while( token != NULL ) {
        //check if is recorded
        int duplicate = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < wordCount+1; ++j){
                if(strcmp(token, wordArray[j]) == 0){
                    ++wordCountArray[j];
                    ++duplicate;
                    break;
                }
        }
        //UNRECORDED / not duplicate
        if(duplicate < 1){
            printf("UNIQEUE WORD: ");
            char wordCopy[strlen(token)+1];
            strcpy(wordCopy, token);
            strcpy(wordArray[wordCount], wordCopy);
            wordCountArray[wordCount] = 1;
            printf("%s\n", wordArray[wordCount]);

            for(int i = 0; i < wordCount+1; ++i){
                printf("#%d: %s\n", i, wordArray[i]);
            }
            ++wordCount;
        }
        //end sequence
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }```
````

Comment: How is `wordArray` declared? Did you allocate enough memory for it? Please provide all the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide a [mcve]. Also read [this].

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have fixed my OP

Comment: you declare your `wordArray` as `[1][256]`, this means you will go out of bounds at the second word tat is not a duplicate. Have you tried to run the program with only 1 word or with only 1 word repeated multiple times? Does it give the expected output?

Comment: Is it not the case that when a new word is found, the wordCount variable is incremented and thus the bounds of wordArray are expanded? ( wordArray[wordCount+1][256] )


I tried your advice with using different strings, it works fine untill a second unique word is found, then wordArray is messed up.

EDIT: I just tried setting the bounds of wordArray as wordArray[256][256] which resolved this undefined behaviour i was seeing before. 


Still i'd like to understand why my method didn't work.